# Ability to split two questions into two seperate questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So sometimes a person asks a question which has two parts to it. And two people answer each individual part. Both people answer the question correctly and now the asker of the question is faced with the following problem. Both answers are correct and you can't assign the checkmark to anyone.

Making people seperate questions doesn't seem like a good idea and will make the site harder to use in general.

Can we ask stackexchange if you could assign a successful answer to both answers since they are both correct? Or is there a way for both people to merge each other's answer.

Comment: Hi there. Can you include links to questions where you feel this feature could have been useful?

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31883/5385

Comment: Thanks for the link! Is this a frequent problem? I was hoping you might have additional examples.

Comment: I am in bed trying to sleep at lunch I will find more for you

Comment: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32189/is-this-covering-problem-np-hard/32192#32192 is another question